# ParametricNDSolveValue with coupled DEs and manipulation

Tags: manipulate, list-manipulation, parametric-functions

How do I separate the solutions to these coupled DEs in the plot?

I want to plot the solutions to these equations at time `t=7` as a function of parameter `a` while manipulating parameter `b`.

Code:

```
Manipulate[    
 sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   {s'[t] == -a*b*d[t], d'[t] == +b*s[t], s[0] == 100, d[0] == 0},
   {s[7], d[7]},
   {t, 0, 20},
   {a}
   ];

 Show[{
   Plot[sol[a], {a, 0.1, 10}, ImageSize -> 400, 
    PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}, PlotLabel -> populations]
   }],

 Text["Test-----"],
 {{b, 1, "b"}, 0.1, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

I tried

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[(s[t],d[t])/.sol[a]],{a,0.1,10}]
```

and

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[(s[a][t],d[a][t])/.sol],{a,0.1,10}]
```

and various other lines but Mathematica is giving me errors like "is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing"

Answer (score 2):

Two changes in your code: (1) made `sol` a two-parameter function and evaluate it outside `Manipulate`, (2) used `{sol[a,b][[1]],sol[a,b][[2]]}` as the first argument in `Plot`:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{s'[t] == -a*c*d[t], d'[t] == c*s[t], 
    s[0] == 100, d[0] == 0}, {s[7], d[7]}, {t, 0, 20}, {a, c}];

Manipulate[Plot[{sol[a, b][[1]], sol[a, b][[2]]}, {a, 1/10, 10}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 400, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Blue}], 
 {{b, 1, "b"}, .1, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}]
```

[image]

**Note:** If we use `sol[a,b]` or `Evaluate@sol[a,b]` instead of `{sol[a, b][[1]], sol[a, b][[2]]}` we get two curves with the same color.

Comment: Thanks so much! I have a lot to learn. PerformanceGoal is a nice touch.

Comment: @Takeitfromme, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.